# Texture Paint only draws in black - Blender 2.8

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I am new to Blender, so sorry for my inexperience, so I tried Blender 2.8 for the first time.
I want to texture paint on my 3D Object but it only draws in black, even though I want to use different colours.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: Black lines on the 3D Object, instead of the selected Pink colour]
I also use these Nodes for the texture
[image: Nodes for the Shader]

Comment: What happens when you plug the texture straight into a diffuse shader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve this problem, I just had to change the brush texture. It seems like I messed it up, and put it to black